# Maths Formula Design Pattern

Tags: c#, java, objective-c

For example, i need a function that computes the newton's law F=MA, so i code the following in C#

```
private double calcForce(double mass, double acceleration){
        return mass * acceleration;
}

private double calcMass(double force, double acceleration){
        return force / acceleration;
}

private double calcAcceleration(double force, double mass){
        return force / mass;
}
```

This works fine if the math function has small number of variables(F=MA has only 3), with a more complex function(my real task is deal with heat transfer/fluid mechanics function which easily consists more than 10 variables!) the number of methods will equal to the number of variables in that math function.

So, is there any good design pattern that take care of this. Should i use something like this?

```
private double NewtonsLaw(double? force,double? mass,double? acceleration)
{
        if(!force.HasValue)
            return mass*acceleration;
        //else if
}
```

One more thing, I need to code in objective-c and java instead of C#.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create an object with your mass/acceleration/force values and (depending on which values are set) either calculate them or just return them

```
public class NewtonLaw {
    private Double mass;
    private Double acceleration;
    private Double force;

    public NewtonLaw(Double mass, Double acceleration, Double force) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.acceleration = acceleration;
        this.force = force;
    }

    public Double calcMass() {
        if (mass != null) {
            return mass;
        } else if (acceleration == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Acceleration is not set");
        } else if (acceleration == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Acceleration is zero, cannot calculate the mass");
        } else if (force == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Force is not set");
        } else {
            return force / acceleration;
        }
    }

    public Double calcAcceleration() {
        if (acceleration != null) {
            return acceleration;
        } else ...
    }

    public Double calcForce() {
        if (force != null) {
            return force;
        } else ...
    }
}
```

Admittedly this is a lot of code for just a few calculations but at least the logic is completely encapsulated in the object

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to have a separate method for each possible combination rather than making the user pass nullable types with one value set to null.

If you provide a private constructor that takes all the values and a set of public static factory methods that each accept all but one of the values, it will make the code clearer at the point of call, and it will also mean that you don't need to check that all but one of the values are non-null.

Something like this (written in C# but the concept translates to Java or Objective C easily enough):

```
public class Newton
{
    readonly double _force;
    readonly double _mass;
    readonly double _accel;

    public double Force
    {
        get { return _force; }
    }

    public double Mass
    {
        get { return _mass; }
    }

    public double Accel
    {
        get { return _accel; }
    }

    public static Newton FromForceAndMass(double force, double mass)
    {
        return new Newton(force, mass, calcAccel(force, mass));
    }

    public static Newton FromForceAndAccel(double force, double accel)
    {
        return new Newton(force, calcMass(force, accel), accel);
    }

    public static Newton FromMassAndAccel(double mass, double accel)
    {
        return new Newton(calcForce(mass, accel), mass, accel);
    }

    private static double calcAccel(double force, double mass)
    {
         return force / mass;
    }

    private static double calcForce(double mass, double acceleration)
    {
        return mass * acceleration;
    }

    private static double calcMass(double force, double acceleration)
    {
        return force / acceleration;
    }

    private Newton(double force, double mass, double accel)
    {
        _force = force;
        _mass  = mass;
        _accel = accel;
    }
}
```

(The values are not checked for division by zero - you'd have to add error checking for that.)

Then where you call it, what's happening is more obvious:

```
var newton = Newton.FromForceAndAccel(1.234, 6423.2);
```

This doesn't help with the number of separate methods, but it has a nice usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever pattern you will use, you will have to code the computation of your new values. So it means at least 10 formulae for your heat transfer/fluid mechanics problem.

Putting all those in the same method with optional argument is a bad idea as it will make your code more complex (so more bug, harder to maintain, etc.). Also, you might be wrong in the order of your argument and then calculate something different that what you thing (you think to calculate the mass but you're calculating the acceleration).

It is best to encapsulate those 10 formulae in separate methods. It will easier to implement whatever error checking/handling and easier to debug, test and maintain.

Now, you can encapsulate those 10 methods in an object to will provide you with an interface that is convenient for your own usage. Previous comment contains nice ideas. Choose one that fit you.